# Is there a cross-IDE solution to hint at formatting (like indentation)?

Tags: ide, indentation, code-formatting

Is there a common mechanism to hint at IDE formatting like **indentation** (xxx spaces or tabs), and if yes, how well is it supported ?

I have seen something like that a while ago but I am unable to find back the name, it is a file you put at the root of your project.

Comment: http://editorconfig.org/?

Comment: Yes that is the one, I had something else in mind and was totally blind to it when it appeared in the Google results.

Answer (score 2):

**Format**: [`.editorconfig`](http://editorconfig.org/#overview) file, as suggested in the comments by jonrsharpe, is the thing I was looking for.
The file used by [stackoverflow](https://gist.github.com/NickCraver/3c7fd53e329f7477e17154168025c446) as an example.

**Support**: Beware that some IDEs still have **no native** support for this and a plugin is required http://editorconfig.org/#download

Concerning [line length](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/Property-research:-maximum-line-length), there is some ongoing discussion.

In case you use git, some behavior can enforced via:

- [.gitignore](http://editorconfig.org/#overview) (ignore some files)
- [.gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) (can enforce line endings)

So I would pretty much recommend to have `.editorconfig` and if you use git  `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files at the root of your project.

Any other suggestions ?